# AC Adaptor broke when powering PC case fan

Tags: power-supply, fan

Backstory: I had some arctic cooling F12 PC case fans laying around and wanted to use one to provide additional cooling to my notebook.

I took an "AC Adaptor" I had laying around and hooked it to the fan, it worked fine until the adapter broke while feeling pretty hot.

Fan product page: https://www.arctic.ac/de_en/f12-pwm-pst.html
Works from `5 to 12V`, and should draw about `180mA at 9V` from what I understand from the page.

The ac adapter says: `230V~50Hz to 9V~200mA 1.8VA` (germany)

What was my mistake? Shouldn't the specs be compatible?

**Adapter:**

[image: AC Adaptor label foto]

Comment: Can you post a picture of the adapter?  I think your adapter has AC output while the fan needs DC. I'd like to see the adapter to make sure.

Comment: Sure – https://drive.google.com/open?id=13b133NrbSpaV3H812fLYdUtDG18K0Gbk

Comment: As JRE says - note that the "~50HZ"  means 50 cycles per second AC - and the "9V~" almost certainly means 9V AC. While some people MAY use the "~"  symbol as a separator in other contexts that would be EXTREMELY sloppy and unusual in this context. It is essentially certain here that it means the output is AC. You need DC.

Comment: From Photo -> Yes. AC output. Now DC 0V :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adapter has an AC output.  Your fan expects DC.

I expect the AC adapter was "seeing" a short circuit for half of each AC wave and overheated.

Such adapters have a fusible link on the primary side (where it plugs into the wall.)

If the transformer gets too hot, the link opens and the transformer is dead - permanently.  This is on purpose.  It prevents a shorted transformer from burning down your house.

---

As Russell McMahon mentioned in the comments, the ~ is a give away in the output specification.

All together, there are a few things that point to the output being AC:

1. The ~ in the output voltage specification.  DC would have a symbol that looks more like a couple of equal  signs(==).
2. It specifies a primary and secondary voltage.  Secondary is a term that applies to transformers, so the output will be AC.  Power supplies with DC output usually say "Output" rather than secondary
3. The output power rating is in VA rather than watts.  VA is used in reference to AC power rather than DC.

Comment: Also, the fact that it says 1.8 VA instead of 1.8 watts is fairly convincing too. +1

Comment: Thanks – feeling a bit stupid now, somehow though most of those household devices would work with DC. Grabbed the wrong one from the old box I guess. I see the difference now.